# In Oracle SQL Devleoper, when I copy the results, how can I copy the column headings too?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Devleoper, when I copy the results, how can I copy the column headings too?

For example, I don't want:

```
doucette matthew xona.com etc.
```

I want:

```
lastname firstname url      etc.
-------- --------- -------- ----
doucette matthew   xona.com etc.
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I found the answer on https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2162606. Once you have selected the results (Ctrl +A) then use Ctrl + Shift + C to copy, this will copy the headers aswell.

Regards

Comment: I'll mark this as the winning answer, for its simplicity. Thank you!

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+C` works when running SQL Developer on OS X; `Command+Shift+C` does not (`Command+C` is copy on OS X).

Comment: What a hidden feature!  Even if select all (Ctrl+A), then check Edit menu (Alt+E), you will see: Ctrl+Shift+C -> "Copy Path".  This is like the NES Contra Code of Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: @craig Adding to this; when using Oracle SQL Developer Version 18.2.0.183 on a Virtual Machine (Windows 10 Enterprise)  from a MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur 11.6.8:   {Command+Shift+C} does work whilst {Ctrl+Shift+C} does not. Then, counterintuitively, when pasting the copied value, it is necessary to revert back to using {Ctrl+Shift+V}.

Comment: SQL Developer 21+: Ctrl+Shift+C is mapped to menu item: Edit -> Copy Path.  This answer is no longer correct.  See the answer from @IanCarpenter below.  What a pain.

Comment: Thanks man, you made my day

Answer (score 11):

In SQL Developer 3.0.04, once you have run your query, right click on the results grid and select export....

[image]

Complete the dialogue box as follows.....

[image]

Select next, then finish and then paste into the destination program

Comment: I am using 3.0.04 too, but I am not sure what settings to use in the "Export Wizard". (P.S. Your post does not have the images you intended to post.)

Comment: Where you say "Your post does not have the images you intended to post" What do you see? When viewing my response I can see the two images I posted. Here are the image URL's: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eyAMj.jpg and http://i.stack.imgur.com/osbpq.jpg

Comment: Ah, sorry. My workplace has blocked imgur.com. So frustrating. And stackoverflow 'knows' it's blocked and shows the `enter image description here` text instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you execute your query using "Run Script" (F5) then your output gets shown in the query results window with column headers that you can copy. That is, if I'm understanding what you want correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but incorrect to what I want. The results are shown in the "Query Result" windows, but when I copy them, using Ctrl-A, it does not copy the column headers. This is what I want!